# Assembly x86 , greeting program

Tags: assembly, x86

I tried to write simple greeting program using assembly x86 that takes user name and print out "Hello [userName]"
the problem is the first char of user name is doubled when printing the greeting msg  , for example :

input :

```
Black Knight
```

output :

```
Hello BBlack Knight
```

and here's my code

```
global _start 

section .data 
    msg1        db "Hello "
    user_input  times 20 db 0 


section .bss 

section .text 

_start : 

; read 
mov eax , 3 
mov ebx , 0
mov ecx , user_input
mov edx , 20
int 0x80

; write 
mov eax , 4
mov ebx , 1
mov ecx , msg1
mov edx , 7
int 0x80

mov eax , 4 
mov ebx , 1
mov ecx , user_input
mov edx , 20
int 0x80

; exit 
mov eax , 1
mov ebx , 0
int 0x80
```

Comment: If your user_input buffer follows msg1 directly in memory (like above), you can also output it as one big string in one call, ie. ecx = msg1, edx = 6+20. (looks like nice example for students, that in Assembly there are no variables, but computer memory constituting of consecutive bytes, and your code is completely responsible for giving it all that "structural" meaning known from high level languages, the labels are just aliases of memory addresses, nothing more). So by the memory layout you defined you made the user input to append to msg1 in the memory and that can be exploited during write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of this code:

```
; write 
mov eax , 4
mov ebx , 1
mov ecx , msg1
mov edx , 7
int 0x80
```

You are here telling the write instruction that the string to print is 7 bytes in length when it is, in fact, 6.

Why the doubled B?  Because in memory, the inputted name appears beginning in the byte *immediately* following `msg1`.

You could solve this by printing only 6 characters (Hello + space) or by adding a null terminator to the end of your `msg` value.